# What kind of health cares do I need to have before traveling to Brazil and in Brazil?

Tags: health, brazil

Do I need any specific vaccinations or other kind of prophylaxis before traveling to Brazil?

In Brazil are there any specific cares I should have? specifically for Dengue?

I am going to Rio, but advice in other areas like Salvador is welcome.

Comment: The answer to this will at least partially depend on the vaccination routine in your home country.

Comment: Brazil is a large country, and the vaccinations required vary throughout. Where in Brazil do you intend to travel?

Comment: @Calchas I aaded it in the question.

Comment: This might help you a LOT regarding travel (health care) insurance if you don't already have one http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/776/long-term-travel-what-insurances-can-should-i-get/46751#46751

Answer (score 5):

With regards to before you go - it depends where you are from, where in the country you are going and what you are concerned about.

The UK Foreign Office provides advice here. http://www.nathnac.org/ds/c_pages/country_page_BR.htm

It draws attention to:

- Yellow Fever
- Diptheria
- Hepatitis A
- Rabies
- Teatnus
- Tuberculosis
- Typhoid
- Malaria
- Altitiude
- SCHISTOSOMIASIS
- Dengue Fever

Answer (score 3):

Most of the information provided below can be found on Brazilian Health Ministry website, in the section for [Traveler's Health](http://portalsaude.saude.gov.br/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=9652&Itemid=509). I recommend to read it, as it is a credible source of information for traveler's coming to Brazil.

1. Brazil does not require the International Certificate of Vaccination or Prophylaxis for entry into the country.
2. About Dengue (and other  diseases transmitted by mosquitoes) now that *the winter is coming* (sorry [GoT](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Winter_is_Coming) fans) it becomes less of a threat. In any way it is a good measure to stay in places that have protective screens on doors and windows, especially away from the capital and major cities and also apply repellent to exposed areas of your skin.

   You specifically asked for Rio and Salvador, those are major cities so Dengue is less of a concern than rural areas. Are you planning trips off those cities?

Comment: I am planning to visit Paraty, do some walking nature near Rio and maybe near Salvador also. I heard about really nice place in the region.

Comment: @nsn Paraty is really beautiful. Driving from Rio to Paraty you'll pass by Angra dos Reis, which is really nice too. Certainly recommend it. Back to your original question, on those places it is advisable to take precautions not to be bitten by mosquitoes, but no need to worry too much.